# Change the color of an ellipse based off a boolean

Tags: c#, wpf, datatrigger

```xaml
<Grid Grid.Row="1" Width="500" Height="500">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Ellipse Fill="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="25" Margin="0,0,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="25"/>
    <Ellipse Fill="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="25" Margin="0,0,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="25" Grid.Row="1"/>
    <Ellipse Fill="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="25" Margin="0,0,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="25" Grid.Row="3"/>
    <Ellipse Fill="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="25" Margin="0,0,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="25" Grid.Column="4"/>
    <Ellipse Fill="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="25" Margin="0,0,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="25" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="4"/>
</Grid>
```

Given the above XAML I want the dots to be green when a property is true. I'm assuming I'd do it with a DataTrigger, but the only way I can think of doing it involved duplicating it for each ellipse. It seems hackish to me and was wondering if their is a better solution. Each ellipse is based of a single property, but again that seems like a lot of duplicate code. Ideally what I want is this view to reflect the state of a list of "Stations" using a boolean to determine if they're available or not. The state of each is one-way and won't change while the view is up.

I'm far to new at WPF and XAML to come up with an elegant solution. I cringe every time I attempt something as it just seems like a complete hack.

EDIT:
Thanks to @Alastair's answer I've gotten it working.

Comment: So will you be showing a list of these stations? Eg. The colored circle then their name?

Comment: No actually. Think of it more like a map legend. Each ellipse represents a kiosk on a floor plan.

Comment: I see you have an ellipse within an inner usercontrol. Does the DataContext of your outer UserControl have a IsAvailable Property?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So I would make a custom `UserControl` that contains an Ellipse.

You can then put a the datatrigger into the `UserControl`. You then bind the `DataContext` of the custom control to your boolean property, then bind the `DataTrigger` to the `DataContext` of your `UserControl`.

Thus you are able to keep your XAML clean.

EDIT:

A basic user control. THis should be defined in a separate file, as opposed to a resource. Just right-click the project -> Add -> New Item... then choose WPF UserControl.

```
<UserControl x:Class="Test_WPF.MyEllipseControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <Ellipse  HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                  Height="25"
                  Margin="0,0,0,0"
                  Stroke="Black"
                  VerticalAlignment="Center"
                  Width="25" 
                  Fill="Red">
            <Ellipse.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Ellipse">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsAvailable}"
                                     Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Fill"
                                    Value="Green" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Ellipse.Style>
        </Ellipse>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

and then you'd use it:

```
<local:MyEllipseControl DataContext="{Binding Path=Station1}" />
```

where the `local` namespace is just your local projects namespace.

Comment: Okay. I think I got that. Let's see how it goes.

Comment: I've updated my OP to show what I've got as far as my `UserControl`. I think what I have is mostly correct, just not sure how to actually use it.

Comment: As far as setting the data context. Would I need properties for each "Station". Station1, Station2, etc. Or is it possible to use a list and reference them by index? Stations[0], Stations[1], etc?

Comment: @lose_the_grimm: Hmm, it really depends on how many you have. If you have < 5 or so I would probably go with individual properties. If you have a lot, then maybe you need to look into using a `ItemsControl` or some other list control to easily display a list of them. Sorry for a vague answer, it kinda depends on what you want it to look like and how your ViewModel is set up.

Comment: It's a small number of them so using a property for each wouldn't be too bad. I'm still not sure how to actually invoke the UserControl though. Something like `<ContentControl Content="EllipseBoolean" DataContext="{Binding Path=Station1}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="4" />`? Something tells me it's not that easy. =)

Comment: @lose_the_grimm: Assuming the `Station1` property is a type that has a `IsAvailable` boolean property, then it will work fine. I've updated my answer with an example of how you might structure it.

Comment: Thanks much @Alastair this worked well. One thing though, setting the `Fill="Red"` with the element is overriding the trigger so I used `<Setter Property="Fill" Value="Red" />` just outside and above the `<Style.Triggers></Style.Triggers>`. Then it worked great!

Comment: Another alternative to using the data triggers would be to use a value converter.  I think they end up making the XAML a little easier to read. Then your Fill property would just be `Fill="{Binding Path=IsAvailable, Converter="{StaticResource BooleanToColorConverter}}"` Useful link: http://wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html

Answer (score 5):

Another approach is to bind the fill to your Boolean value directly and use a converter to change the style as you want.

Your converter might look something like this:

```
    class StatusToColor : IValueConverter
    {
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
            {
                SolidColorBrush retColor = new SolidColorBrush();
                retColor.Color = System.Windows.Media.Color.FromRgb(0, 0, 0);
                if ((bool)value)
                {
                     retColor.Color = System.Windows.Media.Color.FromRgb(255, 0, 0);
                }
                else
                {
                     retColor.Color = System.Windows.Media.Color.FromRgb(0, 128, 0);
                }
                return retColor;
            }

            public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
}
```

You can then define the converter in your xaml resources:

```
<Window>    
    <Window.Resources>
        <c:StatusToColor x:Key="MyConverter"/>
    </Window.Resources>
...
```

And set up your bindings as such:

```
<Ellipse Fill="{Binding SomeProperty, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="25" Margin="0,0,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="25"/>
```